# I am getting Login page after given the command slc arc

Tags: node.js, strongloop, loopback

I am new Strongloop pm. I am getting a problem when I am trying to use slc arc.
It is showing log in page in local host. I do not have an account. When I am trying to register it is routing to https://strongloop.com/register/ url which is not found.

Can you please help me?

How to use it?